# Buying Low Volume Populated PCBs and Handling Passive PNs

Tags: components, eaglecad, assembly, beaglebone-black, hobbyist

New to Eagle PCB design. I plan on making a custom Beaglebone Black Wireless PCB, and so have pulled down the Eagle files. I'm a student and have a student license. This project will be too difficult to assemble myself, because of the large BGA component and so forth, so I plan on purchasing the boards assembled. In order for the fab. house to know what parts to put on it, they will need a BOM.

My question is this:

How come none of the passives in the Eagle files has manufacturers or manufacturer part numbers? Am I to take it the fab. house can populate generics from Panasonic or something? If so that's great, but it seems like a lot of work to put on the fab house to source this? If not, how would you recommend going about this?

Thanks for the insights

Answer (score 2):

Some assembly houses have a stock of generic passives that they prefer, since they can keep full reels of them on hand.  Others insist that you provide a manufacturer and part number for every component.  YMMV!

Comment: Thank God. I find picking a manufacturer for each PN very intimidating. And then they'd have to buy a few dozen of each PN, driving the price up about a 1000 percent. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Eh, it's not so bad if you do need to provide MPNs. At least that way you know what you're getting.  Just pick any of the many reputable manufacturers, find their general-purpose 1℅ 0603 range (or whatever), figure out the product code scheme and churn 'em out for all the values in your BOM.  A bit of spreadsheet formula work or a Perl script will speed it up.